# Can´t connect via JavaScript/Websockets with Firefox (after update?)

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

I have an AngularJS App and I am using Websockets to connect to the Server:

```
_ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost");
```

In FireFox I get now following error (FireBug):

```
The connection to ws://localhost/ was aborted, while the page was loading. (Translated by me from German).
```

It was always working, so I have the feeling the last Firefox update is causing the problem (current version: 37.0.1

Its still working with all other Browser I tested with (Chrome, InternetExplorer, some mobile Browser on my Android).

Anyone could know what the problem is here? Thank you very much!

Comment: Nobody has an idea? Anything I could at least try?

Comment: You could try downgrading Firefox and see if it works, just to narrow down the issue to the particular Firefox version.